# Creating a pydatinc Enum from a string

Tags: python, pydantic

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from uuid import UUID
from enum import Enum
from datetime import datetime


class NoteTemplate(str, Enum):
    general_practitioner = "general_practitioner"
    cardiologist = "cardiologist"
    soap = "soap"
    consultation_report = "consultation_report"
    plastic_surgeon = "plastic_surgeon"
    orthopedist = "orthopedist"
```

I would like to create a NoteTemplate from a string.
e.g.

```
NoteTemplate("general_practitioner")
```

Comment: Note sure what this has to do with Pydantic; `NoteTemplate("general_practitioner")` returns `NoteTemplate.general_practicioner` without creating a new instance of `NodeTemplate`. (Classes using the `EnumType` metaclass behave quite differently from regular classes defined using `type`.)

Comment: Does any of these work?  `NoteTemplate.general_practicioner` or `getattr(NoteTemplate, "general_practicioner")`

Comment: I have tried: NoteTemplate("general_practitioner") and got TypeError: NoteTemplate.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given @chepner